# What is the proper way to dim the screen?

Tags: android

I have seen 2 methods so far in my search, both of which I am having trouble with.

Method 1)

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 100);
```

Method 2)

```
IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));
hardware.setScreenBacklight(.5);
```

Which of these methods is correct? Or is there another that I should be using?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I use the code below to do the same

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = getWindow().getAttributes();
WMLP.screenBrightness = 0.15F;
getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
```

The advantage of using the above code is that this affects the screen brightness only in the activity that calls it. So when I move to some other activity (or) quit the application, the phone's default brightness (As set by the user) is restored.

Edit:
I forgot to mention that the range of the screenBrightness attribute is 0.0 - 1.0

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = getWindow().getAttributes();
 if(WMLP.screenBrightness!=0.0f)
 {
     WMLP.screenBrightness              = 0.0F;
     getWindow().setAttributes            (WMLP);
}
Nope this does not work. It reports that the value has been changed to 0.0f but the screen is brighter than ever.

Answer (score -1):

android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.DIM_SCREEN, time); where time is in milli seconds. but this Settings.System.DIM_SCREEN is depricated.