# How to dim screen to zero without conflicting with FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android, android-screen

I found several methods to dim the screen but I am unsure how they work in concert with [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on/2134602#2134602):

- [Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496806/what-is-the-proper-way-to-dim-the-screen)
- [IHardwareService.setScreenBacklight()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496806/what-is-the-proper-way-to-dim-the-screen)
- [WindowManager.LayoutParams.screenBrightness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496806/what-is-the-proper-way-to-dim-the-screen/5287368#5287368)

Which of the above methods will keep the screen on, even if I set brightness to **0.0**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing will work reliably. If you set the brightness to 0 on some devices it will turn off the screen (but the device will be in a funny state for about 5 seconds or so before really realizing it's off and acting as such). Some devices it will be on but black.

IIRC LayoutParams.screenBrightness with a value less than 30 is unreliable in that it might turn off the display.

On an AMOLED device a full screen that's all black will not have backlight. But SLCD definitely will. Also on Android 3.0 you can't have a full screen as the system bar is always visible.