# How can I turn off only the LCD (not making a sleep mode) programmatically with Android?

Tags: android, profile, trepn

I'm trying to use [Trepn](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/increase-app-performance/trepn-profiler) for measuring power consumption of an Android device.

What I found was that LCD consumes most of the power, so in order to get relatively accurate power consumption, I'd better turn off **only** the LCD before the experiment and turn on after the experiment.

How can I turn off only the LCD (not making a sleep mode) programmatically with Android?

Comment: Look at this one, it's very similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274390/android-turn-off-screen-without-going-in-standby-mode

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks like you may already have an answer for your question I wanted to inquire whether you are using Trepn to measure battery power only, or whether you were using per-rail power measurements? Per-rail measurements can make it easier to isolate individual hardware components.

Lastly, for those who haven't already seen it, there is a good article on the Android website that provides suggestions how to measure component power. https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power.html#component-power

- Rick Schwartz - Trepn Product Manager

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Trepn Profiler, it has a feature to keep the device awake during profiling sessions, even if the screen is off.

This can be enabled in Trepn Settings:

> Settings → General → Enable "Acquire Wakelock while Profiling".

You can then start your test and tap the device's Power button to turn the screen off.  Trepn will keep the processor awake for you.

In [Trepn Profiler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quicinc.trepn) 6.0 and higher, this is in "Advanced Mode".