# Android: How to turn off device screen's backlight without stopping the app

Tags: android, root, display, launcher, backlight

Is there a way to programmatically turn off the device screen's backlight (even if it will require a root access), without stopping the application. I've tried to set the minimum brightness level, but it keeps screen on. I need something that will completely turn off the screen, without sending the device to sleep.

Short about the app: The app is a launcher app, and it will be embedded in the ROM, so the app will have root access.

Comment: check if this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/14274390/3497972

Comment: Thanks, but I need this to simulate the screen's off and on, in order to handle hardware button events when the screen is off